# Are there literary clues left by Carroll to help translate The first stanza of ‘Jabberwocky’ into modern English?

Tags: lewis-carroll, through-the-looking-glass

Without asking for a translation of the first stanza of Jabberwocky (a task that would take thousands of words to accomplish), the question here is “did Carroll leave literary clues whereby to attempt to decipher, and perhaps understand, the meaning or meanings of the first (and last) stanza of his most famous poem?

Answer (score 1):

**HUMPTY DUMPTY EXPLAINS IT**

When Alice encounters Humpty Dumpty later in *Through the Looking Glass*, he [explains](http://www76.pair.com/keithlim/jabberwocky/poem/humptydumpty.html) the first verse to her:

> "You seem very clever at explaining words, Sir", said Alice. "Would you kindly tell me the meaning of the poem 'Jabberwocky'?"
>
> "Let's hear it", said Humpty Dumpty. "I can explain all the poems that ever were invented--and a good many that haven't been invented
> just yet."
>
> This sounded very hopeful, so Alice repeated the first verse:
>
> 'Twas brillig, and the slithy toves Did gyre and gimble in the wabe: All mimsy were the borogoves, And the mome raths outgrabe.
>
> "That's enough to begin with", Humpty Dumpty interrupted: "there are plenty of hard words there. 'Brillig' means four o'clock in the
> afternoon--the time when you begin broiling things for dinner."
>
> "That'll do very well", said Alice: "and 'slithy'?"
>
> Well, 'slithy' means 'lithe and slimy'. 'Lithe' is the same as 'active'. You see it's like a portmanteau--there are two meanings
> packed up into one word."
>
> "I see it now", Alice remarked thoughfully: "and what are 'toves'?"
>
> "Well, 'toves' are something like badgers--they're something like lizards--and they're something like corkscrews."
>
> "They must be very curious creatures."
>
> "They are that", said Humpty Dumpty: "also they make their nests under sun-dials--also they live on cheese."
>
> "And what's to 'gyre' and to 'gimble'?"
>
> "To 'gyre' is to go round and round like a gyroscope. To 'gimble' is to make holes like a gimlet."
>
> "And 'the wabe' is the grass plot round a sun-dial, I suppose?" said Alice, surprised at her own ingenuity.
>
> "Of course it is. It's called 'wabe', you know, because it goes a long way before it, and a long way behind it--"
>
> "And a long way beyond it on each side", Alice added.
>
> "Exactly so. Well then, 'mimsy' is 'flimsy and miserable' (there's another portmanteau for you). And a 'borogove' is a thin
> shabby-looking bird with its feathers sticking out all
> round--something like a live mop."
>
> "And then 'mome raths'?" said Alice. "If I'm not giving you too much trouble."
>
> "Well a 'rath' is a sort of green pig, but 'mome' I'm not certain about. I think it's sort for 'from home'--meaning that they'd lost
> their way, you know."
>
> "And what does 'outgrabe' mean?"
>
> "Well, 'outgribing' is something between bellowing an whistling, with a kind of sneeze in the middle: however, you'll hear it done,
> maybe--down in the wood yonder--and when you've once heard it, you'll
> be quite content. Who's been repeating all that hard stuff to you?"
>
> "I read it in a book", said Alice.

Wikipedia has a [list of possible meanings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jabberwocky#Possible_interpretations_of_words) of other words in the poem, some of them credited to Carroll himself.

Answer (score 0):

A twenty-three year old Dodgson/Carroll penned a version of the first stanza of ‘Jabberwocky’ in 1855, in a family magazine, aptly called *Mischmasch*. There we find a version of the first part of ‘Jabberwocky,’ as ‘A Stanza of Anglo-Saxon Poetry,’ and its counterpart below, spelled out in “modern characters”:

> T’AS BRYLLYG, AND THE SLYTHY TOVES
> DID GYRE AND GYMBLE IN THE WABE:
> ALL MIMSY WERE THE BOROGOVES;
> AND THE MOME RATHS OUTGRABE. (In Carroll’s *The Rectory Umbrella
> and Mischmasch*, p. 139)

From there Carroll supplies a “nonsense” glossary of every one of the terms he used, a “nonsense” “literal English” translation, and a “nonsense” explanation of the ‘Stanza.’ These Carrollian aids, which he provides for the understanding of the precursor to the famous poem, in addition to all the help that Humpty Dumpy give in *Through the Looking-Glass*, for the comprehension of ‘Jabberwocky,’ should provide curious readers with very good starting points in a search for answers.